# Cant make Angular-Gridster example work

Tags: angularjs, gridster

I'm trying to implement Angular-Gridster, but I can't get the example to work for me.

It seems the gridster module doesn't get injected anywhere or something

```
<div gridster="gridsterOpts">
```

[This is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PoOoZaQ/kg2zx41q/1/)

[Github source](https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster)

[Angular-Gridster site](http://manifestwebdesign.github.io/angular-gridster/)

[The example I'm trying to implement](https://rawgit.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster/master/index.html#/main)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you declare the app you forget to specify the gridster dependency. So it should be like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['gridster']);
```

Also note that JSFIDDE does not load your gridster source in head: Refused to execute script from, so add to your code direct to see the result.

Comment: Tried adding the 'gridster' as you mentioned but nothing changed.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thats so odd, I've modified mine to be exactly as yours and mine is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/PoOoZaQ/kg2zx41q/6/
(I'm getting same behavior in my own app, not just out of pure curiosity)

Comment: What I also did is change the angular-gridster link to use this one: http://rawgit.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster/master/src/angular-gridster.js instead of this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ManifestWebDesign/angular-gridster/master/src/angular-gridster.js